# Not being possible to open local host with dash

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am trying to initialize a dash server in my local host and the following error is shown : `OSError: [Errno 48] Address already in use`

I tried changing port and address from localhost to another one and show me the following error 
`An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.SystemExit: 1`

```py
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html


app = dash.Dash(__name__)
server = app.server

app.layout = html.Div([

    html.H1("Mapa de distribucion Electrica"),
    html.H3("Seleccionar Region")

])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

The default port for Dash server is 8050. Seems something is already using that port. You can find out what & stop it..... or you can run Dash on a different port by passing the `port` param to the `run_server`

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, port=8051) # or whatever you choose
```

Comment: thank you, but whenever i change the port i have the following error ```An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.SystemExit: 1```

Comment: Can you check the server log?